# Getting a string from JSON response and adding 1 to it

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a RESTful GET request from a ticketing system. It gets the most recent ticket number entered in the system, and prints it for the user. What I need to do is then take the number it gives, and add one to it for a POST request. For example, here's my code:

```
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    data2 = response.json()
    ntickId = data2[0]['id']
    if tickId < ntickId:
        pprint(f"The most recent ticket is: {ntickId}. Press any key to continue.")
        input(" ")
        pprint(f"Your new ticket number will be: " + int({ntickId})+1)
```

Earlier, I entered the number 468516. Here's my output:

```
Please Enter Event Ticket ID: 468516
'The most recent ticket is: 468999. Press any key to continue.
```

So far so good. So, *ideally* I'd expect 469000 to be the new ticket number. Here's what I got instead:

```
pprint(f"Your new ticket number will be: " + int({ntickId})+1)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'set'
```

I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: What did you _expect_ `{ntickId}` to do? You're not inside an `f`-string there.

Comment: Why do you use a format-literad string  `f"Your new ticket number will be: "`  and try to add an integer to it? Why do you try to make an int() out of a set?

Comment: Will multiple workers be running this code? Because, if so, you may run into issues with collisions of ticket numbers

Comment: No, just me. Also, when taking the "int" out I get:

pprint(f"Your new ticket number will be: " + ({ntickId})+1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "set") to str

Comment: [How to f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) - dont use + to string concattenate. Format the number INTO the string.

Comment: To clarify, when I say workers, I mean in the sense of multithreading or multiprocessing and not physical humans.  Also, Python thinks the value is a `set` so you need to find a way to cast [a set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to an int.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'm not entirely sure, if I'm honest. Is there a way for me to check it?

Comment: Should be in the documentation for the server you're going to use to deploy the application

Comment: We haven't decided on a server yet. It will likely be a VM in our cloud, but nothing will be set up until I can show the code works

Comment: I realized this after I commented but wanted to point out, `{` brackets inside f-strings mean interpolated values but outside f-strings they are the set literal notation which is why Python thought you had a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
pprint(f"Your new ticket number will be: {int(ntickId)+1}")
```

Note, given that you compare `tickId` and `ntickId` conversion to int is most likely not necessary  because `ntickId` is already an int. You may edit your question to include sample JSON response from the API. In this case:

```
pprint(f"Your new ticket number will be: {ntickId+1}")
```

Comment: This worked, but I also found that:


 pprint(f"The most recent ticket is: {ntickId}. Press any key to continue.")
input(" ")
int(ntickId)
ptickId = ntickId + 1pprint(f"Your new ticket number is {ptickId}. Press any key to continue.")

worked as well

Comment: Of course you can  increment value on separate line and bind it to new name and then use that name in f-string. However my understanding was that the whole purpose of the question is to do the calculation inside the f-string. And frankly - it's more convenient given that it is a simple calculation.

Comment: And by the way - the title is misleading because obviously you are not getting a string from JSON, but int.